# How to update Gnome to 3.4?

Tags: installation, gnome

I read about release new GNOME 3.4.
How to update from GNOME 3.2 (upgrade manager does not tell me about the new Update when check).

Comment: related question -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/117017/how-to-install-gnome-3-4-ubuntu and http://askubuntu.com/questions/116978/upgrading-to-gnome-shell-3-4-in-ubuntu-11-10-broke-both-unity-and-gnome-shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are on Ubuntu, 11.10 since you have Gnome 3.2. You would have to upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04 when it is available in order to get Gnome 3.4, unless you want to use the (risky) Gnome 3 PPA.

Comment: Why is it considered risky? Only the fact that it is not maintained by Canonical?

Comment: @KaustubhP: it is risky because it sometimes breaks packages (I have tried it before and it did).

Comment: The GNOME3 PPA only has GNOME 3.2 for Ubuntu 11.10. It's the experimental ricotz testing PPA that adds 3.4 for 11.10.

Answer (score 6):

Gnome 3.4 will be available in the default Ubuntu repositories for the 12.10 release. Ubuntu 12.04 LTS uses many 3.4 components, but to install it in full, add [the GNOME3 team's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3) to your Software Sources.

Keep in mind that Gnome is a major component of your user experience, and — in this PPA — is being maintained by a third party, not Canonical. Instability may occur.

#### References

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Comment: eh, 12.04 has Gnome 3.4 (I'm running 12.04 before you ask)...

Comment: @RolandTaylor Not entirely. It draws a few components from 3.4, but also uses a lot of 3.0 and 3.2 elements in the interest of platform stability

Comment: @RolandTaylor https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/desktop-p-gnome-version

Comment: shall I add a screenshot of which version I have installed?

Comment: I'm not sure if you know, but the problem holding back Gnome Shell 3.4 (and some other components) has been resolved. Only a few applications have been held back.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu
From Ubuntu 11.10 onwards, GNOME 3 is just a 
[click away.](http://www.gnome.org/getting-gnome/)

Comment: That just installs the existing version of gnome in Ubuntu.  This question is asking about upgrading to a newer version than the one in Ubuntu.