# Upgrading to Gnome 3.4 breaks Unity and gnome-shell in 11.10

Tags: unity, gnome

I have upgraded my gnome shell to 3.4 in Ubuntu 11.10 through

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/testing 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

But it broke my system. Gnome shell is completely broken - When I login it just shows desktop wallpaper and nothing else.

And importantly Unity is also broken. Attaching the screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Some main issues

1)Two menus are appearing now - Global menu as well as application menu
2)Icons on top-right panel are appearing weirdly
3)My Default Ambiance Theme also got screwed. Instead of black color menus, I am seeing white color menus.

How do I fix them? Or Do I have an option to revert back to original settings or will reinstalling Unity/Gnome Shell helps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution to your problem is to install Ubuntu 12.04 as Jeremy suggested above.  Rather than spend countless hours trying to find a way to undo the damage you can start fresh.  You can try to upgrade but if it's broken now it may be just as broken when you get done upgrading.  Really it's easier to start with a clean install and avoid using packages that aren't meant to be used with your version of ubuntu.  12.04 is nearly out of beta anyways and will be supported much longer than 11.10.

Answer (score 2):

If you can get to the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ricotz/testing 
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

Comment: GNOME 3.4 isn't supported on Ubuntu 11.10; you'll need to use Ubuntu 12.04 for supported GNOME 3.4.

Comment: Yeah I did the same but still not much use

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Go to a Command Line Interface:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

Login, then type:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity && sudo reboot
```

Comment: did that. Not much use. I guess its not the problem with unity but with gnome settings

Comment: if like that, you have to uninstall gnome and all gnome settings.

type

as the first way, go to command line then login

then type sudo apt-get --purge remove gnome-shell && sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity

finally reboot.