# How To Install Gnome 3.4 Ubuntu?

Tags: gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME Shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome-shell)

Yesterday they released a brand new version of Gnome... How can I install this Gnome 3.4 in Ubuntu?